# Angular compiler showing error: The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to show some data in a chart my Angular 15 app that I get from an API. I have defined the data in file ***chart-data.ts*** like this:

```
export var saleChart: [
  {
    label: string,
    series: [
      {
        datum: string,
        count: number;
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I am getting the data from an API in ***customers.service.ts*** like this:

```
 getSingleCustomerChartData(id:number) {
    return this.httpClient.get(`${environment.apiUrl}stat/sale-chart/${id}`)
  }
```

and in the customer.component.ts the code is:

```
  saleChart = saleChart;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getSingleCustomerChartData();
  }

  getSingleCustomerChartData() {
    const id = Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
    this.customerService.getSingleCustomerChartData(id).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.saleChart = data;
        console.log('Chart data: ', data);
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error', error);
      });
  }
```

My code does not compile and I am getting this error:

> Error: src/app/customers/customer/customer.component.ts:138:9 - error
> TS2322: Type 'Object' is not assignable to type '[{ label: string;
> series: [{ datum: string; count: number; }]; }]'.   The 'Object' type
> is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any'
> type instead?

What have I done wrong? where is my mistake?

Comment: You must be sure that your exported saleChart and the sale chart response of the API are of the same type (interface / class). Try to add the type to the http client get like this: ```return this.httpClient.get<YOUR_INTERFACE_OR_CLASS(`${environment.apiUrl}stat/sale-chart/${id}`)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define your `types` properly or keep the type as `any`.
You can use like this

```
type dataSeries = {
  datum: string;
  count: number;
};
type salesData = {
  label: string;
  series: dataSeries[];
};
export var saleChart: salesData[];
```

You also have to use the types in the `http-client`

```
public getSalesdata(): Observable<salesData[]> {
    return this.http.get<salesData[]>(`your api`);
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error now: The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
  Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'salesData[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.